# Google Recaptcha PHP Not Working

Tags: php, html, forms, recaptcha

I have been building a Google ReCaptcha into a simple contact me form. I have been working on this for a couple of days now and I feel like there are 10 different ways to do it, but not of it "makes sense" or has clicked so far. The current code I have down is what I feel like would make sense best for me, but maybe someone else has a better way or tutorial.

Here is my question: Why is my form not connecting to Google's Servers and verifying and why am I not getting an echo when submitted.

CODE:

```
<div class="contactme" id="contactme">
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" name="myemailform" id="myform" action="form-to-email.php">
          <fieldset>
            <h2>Let's Create Together</h2>
            <hr class="small">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
              <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">E-Mail</label>
              <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="visitor_email" placeholder="E-Mail" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message</label>
              <div class="col-lg-10">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" name="message" required></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submitbutton" class="btn btn-primary mainButton">Submit</button>
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="--KEY--"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

PHP on seperate document.

```
    <?php
         if($_POST['submit']) {
             $yoursecret='--KEY--';
$response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$yoursecret."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
            $googleobj = json_decode($response);
            $verified = $googleobj->success;
            if($verified === true){
                //do stuff
                echo "Success!, you have been verified!"; 

            } else {
                echo "No Success!";
            }

        }
    ?>
```

I also strangely get an "=" at the top of page ever since messing PHP and RECAPTCHA. The site is live at [joshkelley.video](http://joshkelley.video) If you submit the form it just takes you to a blank page, regardless of the whether you verify the Recapcha.

Is there a community standard for doing these? All I could find was a few youtube out of date youtube tutorials.

Comment: white screen of death: error checking\display are off, turn them on to see the error. at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: Okay, I now get an error. Its a massive errror with the file_get_contents

Comment: cant help you if you dont tell me\us what exactly the error is

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in

www.joshkelley.video if you want to see it for your self. fill out contact form and press submit.

Comment: "https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration " your host does not allow you to use `file_get_contents` on url's. your host maybe able to change this for you, or you will have to use something else like curl. or you may need to change hosts